# Why is gsub not working whenever GT sign ">" is the first character in regex

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

In the text data I am working on the greather than sign is always supposed to be a final character. Hence, I wanted to replace all non-conforming occurences like that:

```
some_variable.gsub!(/>([^\n])/, ">\n\\1")
```

However, I keep getting the *undefined method `gsub!' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)* error when calling this`gsub!` – even if I escape that character with a backslash.
To my surprise, changing it so that GT sign is not the first one in the regex:

```
some_variable.gsub!(/(.)>([^\n])/,"\\1\n\\2")
```

makes it work. But why? Isn't this weird for `gsub` to return nil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `gsub!`. The error message says that you try to call `gsub!` on `nil`, i.e. it means that `some_variable` is `nil` when you don't expect it to be. The argument to `gsub!`, even the call to `gsub!` itself, is completely irrelevant, your problem is that `some_variable` is `nil` when you expect it to be a `String`.

Comment: OK, but why does `some_variable` go `nil` only when the first character of a regex is `/>/`? I am unable to replicate this with *any* other regex, both with and without any matches.

Comment: Again, this has nothing do with the call to `gsub!` itself, because `gsub!` isn't getting called at all. The error message says that `gsub!` doesn't get called, ergo, the argument to `gsub!` is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Hmm, but how is it possible that `gsub!` is not getting called when the argument is `/>/`, and getting called when the argument is anything not beginning with `>`? I made no other ingerention in the program. The program just loads a file, makes a couple of `gsub`s and prints it. Changing the regex is capable of overriding whether I am calling it or not?

Comment: Weird. I tried to replicate the error by making a 4-line code, but it worked. So you might be right. But I still don't understand why changing the regex changes whether the `gsub!` is being called or not...

Comment: It doesn't. It can't. The method is not found. Since it is not found, it is not executed. Since it is not executed, its arguments are totally and utterly irrelevant. Somewhere, somehow in your program `some_variable` gets assigned to something. You didn't show us where or how. And at that place, it sometimes gets assigned to `nil`. That is the only explanation.

Comment: Still somewhat troublesome. Anyway, thanks for the explanation, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

`gsub!` (destructive) returns nil [when it doesnt modify anything](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub-21)

so its behavior is expected if that regex doesnt match without the wildcard

Comment: But it's still double weird. First of all, the string has a lot of of GTs, both in input and output. Even pure />/ returns the same error.
Second of all, this is the first time I have seen a gsub with 0 matches to turn any string into a nil. I just tested a couple of regexes with 0 matches, and none does turn the string into a nil.